# Python3,divisable by three,typeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

This should be simple. I want to list all the numbers from 1 to 50 that are divisable by 3:

```
a = [i for i in range(1,51) ]

[i for i in a % 3 == 0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-42b9611b86db> in <module>()
----> 1 [i for i in a % 3 == 0]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Why do I get this TypeError?

Comment: I think you want `[i for i in a if i % 3 == 0]`. You left out the `if i` part.

Comment: Also note that `a = [i for i in range(1,51) ]` is better written as `a = list(range(1, 51))`

Comment: and why not just `[3*i for i in range(1, 51//3)]` or even `list(range(3, 51, 3))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments you probably wanted:

```
>>> [i for i in range(1, 51) if i % 3 == 0]  # included an "if"
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48]
```

Alternativly you could directly create them from a modified `range`:

```
>>> [3 * i for i in range(1, 51 // 3)]
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48]

>>> list(range(3, 51, 3))
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48]
```

In your case you get the `TypeError` because you use `a % 3` and `a` is a `list` that doesn't support division or modulo operations.